# Cakephp 3 Download de arquivos grandes

Tags: php, arquivo, cakephp, download

Estou com o seguinte problema.
Minha aplicação Cakephp 3, armazena alguns arquivos GRANDES (200mbs), enviados via FTP. Esses arquivos ficam em uma pasta fora do meu projeto.

Ao clicar no link de download, o mesmo começa a ser enviado para o usuário, porém a navegação do site fica congelada, não permitindo navegar entre outras telas.

```php
// no Controller
public function download($id=null) {
   // ... Acessa o registro para capturar o caminho do arquivocakpehp
   $filePath = '/caminho/do/arquivo.xxx';

   return $this->response
                    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
                    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;')
                    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')
                    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=1')
                    ->withHeader('Expires', 'Mon, 26 Jul 2500 05:00:00 GMT')
                    ->withHeader('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' PDT')
                    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'cache, must-revalidate')
                    ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
                    ->withFile($filePath, ['download' => true]);

}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?
Essa foi uma das maneiras que testei.

Comment: Fica congelado porque provavelmente você esta usando SESSÃO do PHP, mesmo que internamente no FW, antes do `return` tente executar `session_write_close();`. Não sei como funciona no cakephp, talvez nesta sua tela nem seria necessário sessão.

Comment: Show, resolveu meu problema.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Por nada Felipe, fechei como dup, pq a outra resposta que fiz na outra pergunta detalha tudo sobre isto, mas mantenha a sua pergunta, que ela servirá de referencia para a resposta para futuros visitantes ;)